# How to fetch subquery columns in Phalcon

Tags: phalcon

what would be the best way (or any way, because I can't figure out anything blending with Phalcon models at the moment) to fetch data from query like this:

```
SELECT *, (select sum(l.log_volume) from logs l where l.parcel_id = p.parcel_id) as parcel_total_volume 
FROM PARCELS p
```

what I want is to basically have calculated fields easily accessible from model, preferably calculated on sql side and fetched with every record.

If this must be done in model php code instead, then how?

Answer (score 3):

I would go for something like this:

```
<?php

class Parcels extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    private static $sumsCache = [];

    /*
       ...
    */

   public function getTotalVolume()
   {
        if(!isset($sumsCache[$this->parcel_id])) {
            $sumsCache[$this->parcel_id] = Logs::sum("parcel_id = $this->parcel_id");
        }

        return $sumsCache[$this->parcel_id];
   }
}
```

This way you fetch the sum JIT and you store a static cache for each `parcel_id`.

Comment: I like this! This looks like kind of a hack to me, but I take it there is no "Phalcon-friendly" way?

Comment: @lot Yes there is one Phalcon way I think, you could set `parcelTotalVolume` in the `afterFetch` event but it would make the sum for every element retrieved (just like your initial query). This "hack" way is for performance purposes.

Comment: @lot answer updated with a simple cache for the sums

Comment: this solution works, but actually makes related models inaccessible. I guess that  Phalcon already defines __get magic method and it conflicts with your own.

Comment: @lot Just as I suspected... ok, moved it to a method now

Comment: @lot The methods called by _get are not predefined. Magic method _get is effected when you try to call a property that is not apart of the object's public property.